# Reading specific words from a file and storing them in an object

Tags: c++, class, getline

I'm having trouble coding and conceptualizing this project I was assigned. I've looked around for answers to this issue but had little to no luck, maybe it's really obvious. I'm supposed to prompt the user to a filename, the file is assume to have the following format:

Animal:

Name: [value]

Noise: [value]

Legs: [value]

(with no spaces in between)

It should be able to read as many "animal objects" as there are in the file and store them in an animal object class that has 3 parameters (name, noise, legs).

My issue is mostly during the reading in of the file, I can't figure out a good method for reading the file AND storing the information. Here is the code I currently have. Any help with the code I currently have and ideas for storing the values. Sorry if I explained anything poorly, please ask to clarify if I did, thank you in advance.

```
    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    string fileName;
    getline(cin, fileName);
    cout << endl;
    try
    {
        ifstream animalFile(fileName);
        if (!animalFile.good()) // if it's no good, let the user know and let the loop continue to try again
        {
            cout << "There was a problem with the file " << fileName << endl << endl;
            continue;
        }

        string line;
        while (animalFile >> line) // To get you all the lines.
        {
            getline(animalFile, line); // Saves the line in STRING.
            cout << line << endl; // Prints our STRING.
        }

    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "There was a problem with the file " << fileName << endl <<    endl;
    }
```

Comment: Is it really sensible to reinvent the wheel in this case? Consider using existing libraries for xml, json, yaml or anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really binded with this file format, consider doing the following to read the data and store it:

#1. Define a class `Animal` to represent an animal:

```
struct Animal
{
    std::string name;
    int legs;
    int noise;
}
```

#2. Define an `istream& operator >> (istream&, Animal&)` to read one object of this type and check for the correctness of the input.

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& lhs, Animal& rhs)
{
    std::string buf;
    lhs >> buf >> buf >> rhs.name >> buf >> rhs.noise >> buf >> rhs.legs;
}
```

#3. Use `std::copy` and `std::istream_iterator` to read all the values from the file to `std::vector`:

```
std::istream_iterator<Animal> eos;
std::istream_iterator<Animal> bos(animalFile);
std::vector<Animal> zoo;
std::copy(bos, eos, std::back_inserter(zoo));
```

This code has no checking for input errors, which may easily be added into `istream& operator >> (istream&, Animal&)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So for clarification, #2 is simply reading the file to check for the format, nothing else? Also for #3, could you give me an explanation of what which line of code is doing, I'm having trouble completely grasping it, even knowing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @Roberto #2 actually reads the data and returns it by storing in the output argument `rhs`. This operator may be used as follows: `Animal a; cin >> a;`.

Comment: #3: `std::vector` is just a dynamic array of `Animal`s. `istream_iterator<T>` is an iterator over the `istream`. On dereferencing it returns the value of type `T` read from the `istream` given by the `operator >>`, on advancing it moves to the next element of type `T` in the `istream`. `istream_iterator` constructed with no arguments is "end of stream iterator" - it has the wrong state and is equal (in terms of `operator ==`) to the `istream_iterator` advanced until it reaches end of stream. `std::back_inserter` is a `std::back_intert_iterator` which does `push_back()` when assigned to.

Comment: So, in the last line we copy range of iterators pointing to the `Animal` structures from the beginning to the end of `ifstream animalFile` to the `std::vector zoo`, using `push_back` operation (since the data is not reserved for it)

Comment: Useful links: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator/